# Automate R based on text file

Tags: r, bash

I have a text file in the format:

```
>species1
0.432
0.323
0.987
(possibly continued...)
>species2
-0.332
```

and so on...

I have 4 variables, `totalcomsize, totalp, pol_pla, nvp_vp` lets say they are constant so easy to hardcode in. How could I take all the values under `>species1` and plot them vs each of the 4 above-mentioned variables, and then save a plot with the name `species1_vs_variable` where variable is one of the ones above. I want to do this using R, and bash code, can anyone help?

---

**EDITED**

Okay so as a short example, the 4 variables mentioned above correspond to a FIXED set of points, so each one could be `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` for example. Each line beginning with a `>` indicates that there is a new set of data to be compared to each of the 4 aforementioned variables. So `>Species1` could be `>Drosophila Melanogaster`, and EVERY number underneath it separated by a new line is a value included in that set corresponding to D.Melanogaster. But you basically want all the values up until the next line that begins with a `>`. So you may end up with a set `[0.2, 0.4, 0.6]` for the species drosophila melanogaster. Then you want to make a line plot of that dataset for each 4 fixed variables (`totalcomsize, totalp, pol_pla, nvp_vp`) and save the plot, giving it a filename corresponding to the species. I want to automate this because there are MANY MANY species. Which mean #species*4 graphs to manually plot. So you can see why I want to do this. I did manage to put it in a better format where species are tab separated on one line, e.g.

```
anthomyiidae_sp_2_NVP   anthomyiidae_sp_1_NVP   anthomyiidae_sp_3_NVP
-0.221                  0.188                   0.989
0.972                   0.092                   0.924
```

and then their values are on the next line in tab delimited format, and so on until there are no more values. I was able to import this file and it sort of helped. But I could still use a good suggestion.

Comment: Huh? You aren't clear on the file format. Is it always greater-than sign, species label always followed by EXACTLY three (N) numbers?  Then each of your four variables (totalcomsize etc) are also of length three (N)?

Comment: The format is a name like I said prefixed with an `>` followed by any number of digits...

Comment: I will join agstudy's comment and ask you for a small, reproducible example.

Comment: If the number of values is variable how are you going to plot that against the fixed number of values in `totalcomsize`? Its not clear.

Comment: does each of the number after `>species1` correspond to a different variable (if so, why is this number not fixed?) or do they all correspond to one single variable (and if so, how do you distinguish the different variables? one file per variable?)?

Comment: To answer the part about plotting: R is not Matlab.  You can physically create a plot and save it in common formats (pdf,jpg,etc) with whatever file name you wish.  If you want to save the graphic object, take a look at the `ggplot2` package. It's complicated, but once learned, very powerful.

Answer (score 0):

As it is clear on the many comments , what do you want to do .

But, I think the special format of the data is interesting. Since you have data in welle formatted data.frame grouped by species, you can easily play with them.

I read the data with a special separator:

```
dat <- read.table(text ='>species1
0.432
0.323
0.987
>species2
-0.332',sep ='>',fill=TRUE,colClasses=c('numeric','character'))
   dat
      V1       V2
1     NA species1
2  0.432         
3  0.323         
4  0.987         
5     NA species2
6 -0.332
```

I try to fill the gap in the V2 with previous value

```
L <-  dat$V2 != ''
idx <- c(NA,which(L))[cumsum(L)+1]
dat$V2 <- dat$V2[idx]
  dat
      V1       V2
1     NA species1
2  0.432 species1
3  0.323 species1
4  0.987 species1
5     NA species2
6 -0.332 species2
```

Then I remove NA values

```
dat <- na.omit(dat)

     V1       V2
2  0.432 species1
3  0.323 species1
4  0.987 species1
6 -0.332 species2
```

As suggested in the comment , you can create process this on a list indexed by spiecs

```
library(plyr)
ll <- dlply(dat,.(V2),function(x) x$V1)
ll
$species1
[1] 0.432 0.323 0.987

$species2
[1] -0.332
```

Comment: I'd process this to produce a list, indexed by species name.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one file per variable (and assuming your files are named after your variables), here is what I propose:

```
vars <- c("totalcomsize", "totalp", "pol_pla", "nvp_vp")
for(v in vars){
    f <- readLines(paste(v, "txt", sep"."))
    index <- grep(">",f) # Spot lines that start with a >
    mat <- apply(cbind(index, c(index[-1]-1,length(f))), 1,
                        function(X){as.numeric(f[(X[1]+1):X[2]])})
    # break the file at each lines spotted in the preceding step
    names(res) <- gsub(">","",f[index]) # Names each element of the list according to the lines starting with >
    for(i in 1:length(res)){ # Loop to create a plot for each species vs each variable
        pdf(paste(names(res)[i],"_vs_", v, ".pdf",sep=""))
        plot(res[[i]])
        dev.off()
        }
    }
```

For each variable, `res` is a list of the form:

```
res
$species1
[1] 0.432 0.323 0.987
$species2
[1] -0.332
```